# Dynamically loading list in sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a Sencha Touch 2.0 app that is set up with a card layout. It contains a dashboard with icons the user can click on and a customer list (xtype: 'list'). When the app is loaded I load all of the 'cards' in the app including the Customer List, but I don't load the data (via proxy) unless a localStorage variable is set. After everything is loaded I check to see if the user should be logged in automatically by checking the localStorage variable. If they are automatically logged in then my app works perfectly. If they aren't I show them the "login" card, which is basically a login form. Once they submit this log in form I perform an ajax call. If this comes back correctly I send them to the "dashboard" card. But before that I am trying to load the customer list via an ajax call using:

```
var tmpId = { id: example.id };

var cListStore = Ext.create('example.store.CustomerList');
cListStore.getProxy().setExtraParams(tmpid);
cListStore.load();
```

With the code above I can see that my proxy call is happening, and I can see the response is correct. However, when I see the dashboard, and I click on the Customers icon I see an empty list. My toolbar is there and even the indexBar on my list is there, just no data. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I am including my list view, store, and model below, hopefully that will help anyone who looks at this:

```
Ext.define('example.view.CustomerList', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    id: 'customerListContainer',
    xtype: 'customerlist',
    config: {
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top',
            title: 'Customers',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Home',
                id: 'customerListHomeButton',
                ui: 'back'
            }]
        }, {
            xtype: 'list',
            itemTpl: '<div class="contact">{first_name} <strong>{last_name}</strong>  </div>',
            store: 'CustomerList',
            id: 'customer_list',
            grouped: true,
            indexBar: true
        }]
    }
});

Ext.define('example.store.CustomerList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    id: 'customerListStore',
    requires: ['example.model.CustomerList'],
    config: {
        model: 'example.model.CustomerList',
        sorters: 'last_name',
        /*
         * This actually makes the ajax request
         */
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '/example/api/customerList.php',
            extraParams: {
                id: example.id
            },
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: ((example.id > 0) ? true : false), //only fetch the data if we have a id, or else we'll get an error from our api

        /*
         * Set the group headers to the first letter of the last name
         */
        grouper: {
            groupFn: function (record) {
                return record.get('last_name')[0];
            }
        }
    }
});

Ext.define('example.model.CustomerList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        /*
         * Define the fields we get back from our ajax request
         */
        fields: [
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'address1',
            'address2',
            'city',
            'state',
            'zip_code',
            'phone_daytime',
            'phone_evening',
            'phone_cell',
            'email']
    }
});
```

I have also tried to put a storeId in the Customer List store and then use the following code instead of calling Ext.create():

```
Ext.StoreManager.get('storeid').load()
```

This produced the same results. I could see the proxy was fetching the data correctly but it still was rendering in my list component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out, I removed these lines:

```
var cListStore = Ext.create('example.store.CustomerList');
cListStore.getProxy().setExtraParams(tmpid);
cListStore.load();
```

and I added the following in its place:

```
Ext.getStore('CustomerList').getProxy().setExtraParams(tmpid);
Ext.getStore('CustomerList').load();
```

Basically I didn't need to create a new instance of my store, one was already created so I just needed a way to identify it (Ext.getStore) and then load it. Thanks for everyone who looked into it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Sencha Touch 2 expert but I see you set your list store to

```
store: 'CustomerList'
```

And I'm wondering what `CustomerList` is. Shouldn't you set the list's store to `customerListStore` which is your store's id ?

Comment: Actually I don't have a storeId, the id is on my store class. The documentation says to pass a 'store instance' after 'store:' and I don't think that's the problem because if the user is logged in automatically then the customer list works fine. Thanks though.